# boost asio timer do not work with blocking read call

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have following server code. which waits for client to connect and once the client connects it will start thread which receives data from client connected and main thread will wait for another client to connect. This code works fine.

Now I have to specify that server will wait for some time say 10 sec to receive data from connected client. or otherwise server will close the communication if no data received within specified time. I have implemented timer for the same but somehow it doesnt work and `timer_callback` is not called after time elapsed.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

void run(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> my_socket)
{
    while (1)
    {
        char buf[128];
        boost::system::error_code error;

        size_t len = my_socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 128), error);
        std::cout << "len : " << len << std::endl;

        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        {
            cout << "\t(boost::asio::error::eof)" << endl;
            if (my_socket->is_open())
            {
                boost::system::error_code ec;
                cout << "\tSocket closing" << endl;
                my_socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
                cout << "\tShutdown " << ec.message() << endl;
                //cout << "normal close : " << ::close(my_socket->native_handle()) << endl;
                my_socket->close(ec);
                cout << "\tSocket closed" << endl;
            }
            break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
        }
        else if (error)
        {
            std::cout << "Exception : " << error.message() << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                printf("%02x ", buf[i] & 0xFF);
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

void timer_callback(boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> my_socket, const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    std::cout << "timer expired.... " << std::endl;
    if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
    {
        // do something
        std::string str_error = "timer expired  " + error.message();
        my_socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
        my_socket->close();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "timer cancelled ..." << error.message() << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int S = 1000;
    vector<boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread> > arr_thr(S);
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(io_service);

    try
    {
        for (uint32_t i = 0;; i++)
        {

            tcp::endpoint endpoint(tcp::v6(), 10001);

            boost::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> my_socket(new tcp::socket(io_service));
            tcp::endpoint end_type;

            tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, endpoint);

            std::cout << "before accept" << endl;
            acceptor.accept(*my_socket, end_type);

            usleep(10000);

            std::cout << "connected... hdl : " << my_socket->native_handle() << std::endl;

            boost::asio::ip::address addr = end_type.address();
            std::string sClientIp = addr.to_string();

            std::cout << "\tclient IP : " << sClientIp << std::endl;

            timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
            timer.async_wait(
                    boost::bind(&timer_callback, my_socket, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

            arr_thr[i] = boost::shared_ptr<boost::thread>(new boost::thread(&run, my_socket));
        }
    } catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to do the `accept` and `async_wait` from the main thread and do some blocking read on the separate thread.

There are multiple problems with that approach. First your `accept` is blocking, so the timer can't run while the main thread waits for an accept. Also there is no call to `io_service` `run` or `poll`, so the async handler will never be called.

You have to use `async_accept` if you want to mix it with `async_wait` in the same thread.

However you still can't cancel a blocking read on another thread. The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html) states that it's unsafe to use a socket from multiple threads simultaneously (Shared objects: Unsafe).

I would recommend that you use a fully asynchronous design.

Comment: hi I am agree with your suggestion of using fully asynchronous design but the problem is that once I use io_service.stop() & io_service.reset() then io_service.run() gives error.

Comment: This is because there are asynchronous operations pending.
Just design it in a way that when you want to stop your server, stop issuing any async operation or discard errors regarding async pending operations when you want to exit.

Comment: Typically, you don't use `io_service::stop()`and `io_service::reset()` in a simple server. Check the examples in the documentation for an async server sample code.